# How to rebuild a function with three parameters to one?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have here a piece of code *getIsoDate* that works exactly as I want. But later I need to pass it further as one single argument instead of three arguments like I have now (day, month, year).
Thats why I get the error - *Expected 3 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)*

So in order to get rid of the error I need to rebuild getIsoDate that it has one argument but the same function and I am struggling to understand how to achieve that, get rid of day, month, year and use only one value? Or is there another approach? Can you please give me a hint or tip how to start?

```
const getIsoDate = (day: string, month: string, year: string) => {
  if (day && year && month && parseInt(year) > 999)
    return new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}T12:00:00`).toISOString();
  else if (!day && !month && (!year || parseInt(year) < 1000)) return undefined;
  else return "Invalid Date";
```

Comment: What would be the meaning of the single argument? How would it define a date?

Comment: One argument as what? An object? Do you need *both* versions, e.g., an object *or* the three params?

Comment: I have the three params which have the type string and I need to pass only one param for example _fullDate_ as string too.

Comment: @Figario JS/TS isn't great at overloading functions in this way. It's *doable* by (a) marking `month`/`year` as optional and (b) inspecting `day` to guess which form you want--which works against some TS benefits.

Answer (score 1):

You can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the arguments like so if you pass in an object with the corresponding keys:

```js
const getIsoDate = ({ day, month, year}) => {
  if (day && year && month && parseInt(year) > 999)
    return new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}T12:00:00`).toISOString();
  else if (!day && !month && (!year || parseInt(year) < 1000)) return undefined;
  else return "Invalid Date";
}

// exmaple usage
const someDate = { day: '25', month: '04', year: '2022' }
console.log(getIsoDate(someDate))
```

Comment: Thank you, I need to read into destructuring I did not think about this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediate step, first write values and say what type it is (Array with 3 strings). And in the next line you can destructure.
See here:

```
const getIsoDate = (values: [string, string, string]) => {
  const [day, month, year] = values;
  if (day && year && month && parseInt(year) > 999)
    return new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}T12:00:00`).toISOString();
  else if (!day && !month && (!year || parseInt(year) < 1000)) return undefined;
  else return "Invalid Date";
};
```